# Swift: how to support "template method" design pattern (since Swift doesn't have protected)?

Tags: swift, initialization

Traditionally in the "template method" pattern, a base class implements some algorithms and defers to derived classes for specific behavior. This works well in languages like C++/C#/Java because you can use "protected" on those methods to hide them from the callers but keep it visible for derived classes. For example, in the GoF book, you have something like:

```
class Application
{
    void CreateDocument() { ..., this->DoCreateDocument() }
    protected void DoCreateDocument() { } // override for custom behavior
}
```

This keeps the public interface for `Application` clean. In Swift, because you cannot use `protected`, the public interface is not clean. I do not want users of `Application` to see `DoCreateDocument`.

So I'm trying another method, which instead of using methods for `DoCreateDocument`, I'm trying to define a closure and use "functor" patterns.

```
class Application
{
    typealias ActionFunc = () -> ()
    private let doCreateDocument : ActionFunc
    init(a : ActionFunc) { self.doCreateDocument = a }
    func CreateDocument() {
        self.doCreateDocument()
    }
}
```

So this class looks good - the public interface is clean. However, it's impossible to actually use this.

The obvious approach is using a derived class:

```
class DoApplication : Application
{
    init() {
        super.init(
            a : {
                // This would work, but you cannot use self here!
                self. // anything with self. is an error
            })
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that in the initializer, you cannot pass a closure to `super.init` that uses `self`. I get the error `self used before super.init`.

That basically makes it useless because you cannot access any state variables.

However, if you don't initialize `doCreateDocument` in the `init`, you need to expose a setter of some sorts - again, the lack of `protected` means that the setter is on the public API. Yuck.

So is there any way to cleanly implement the template pattern that keeps the interface clean?

Comment: i think ....your problem will be solved if you deifne DoApplication  class in another file than in the same file where Application class is defined..

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an ugly hack, but it works.

```
class DoApplication: Application {
    init() {
        var doCreateDocument: (Application.ActionFunc)!
        super.init(a: { doCreateDocument() })            
        doCreateDocument = { [unowned self] in
            self.foo()
        }
    }

    func foo() {
        println("DoApplication.foo");
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can pass `self` to `doCreateDocument`:

```
class Application {
    typealias ActionFunc = (Application) -> ()
    private let doCreateDocument : ActionFunc

    init(a : ActionFunc) { self.doCreateDocument = a }

    func CreateDocument() {
        self.doCreateDocument(self)
    }
}

class DoApplication : Application {
    init() {
        super.init(a : { _self in
            let _self = _self as! DoApplication

            _self.foo()
        })
    }
    func foo() {
        println("DoApplication.foo");
    }
}
```